# How long do we have contact with a centaur after launch

Tags: flight-computer, atlas-v, separation, centaur

When centaur separates the payload, we can see a video signal of this happening. The mission of centaur is completed now, but are there still some activities centaur is performing after seperation? And how long ULA keeps up transmission? Until battery runs out or short after separation?

Comment: Centaur rockets will sometimes carry rideshare missions that will require an additional burn to position. Also, some rockets (I cannot verify if Centaur does this), will perform an additional burn to place their upper stage into a safe disposal orbit (whether for de-orbiting, or in a graveyard orbit). For both of these, it would be necessary to keep communication open longer to monitor the flight.

Comment: "we can see a video signal of this happening" Can you reference a specific example or two? This is likely to vary from one mission to the next.